# Hash Table Size Setting

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, hash

Do you always have to know the size of the `array` for a `Hashtable` prior to creating the `array`?

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't. A quality implementation (`Hashtable`/`HashMap`) will resize itself automatically as the number of elements increases.

If you are talking about your own implementation, the answer depends on whether the hash table is capable of increasing the number of buckets as its size grows.

If you are worried about the performance implications of the resizing, the correct approach is to profile this in the context of your overall application.

Comment: That would lead to a lot of array copying, no?

Comment: @user: That would lead to *some* copying, sure. However, that copying is unlikely to be the ultimate performance bottleneck of your application, and therefore is probably not worth optimizing. If in doubt, profile.

Comment: +1 to NPE and  @user it increases size in background, which really does not effect the performance of the data structure.

Comment: Just to confirm what I hope is obvious, if you know the number of elements, you should pre-set the size, no?

Comment: @user: If you *know* the number of elements then go for it. It may or may not buy you anything, but it won't do any harm.

Answer (score 0):

No, in fact is bad to have it fixed to a certain value.
For more info you can start here with [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Dynamic_resizing).